# ConnectivityChanged event for internet checking is not working properly in Xamarin ios

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.essentials

I want to check the internet access at run time, using Xamarin essential am trying to achieve  the same. But the event is not triggering properly. Currently it is hitting when the first time the connection lost. Not responding when it again online. Please help me on this. In android it's working fine , the issue is in iOS.

here is my code.

```
BaseViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public bool IsNotConnected { get; set; }
    public BaseViewModel()
    {
        Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged += Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged;
        IsNotConnected = Connectivity.NetworkAccess != NetworkAccess.Internet;
    }

    ~BaseViewModel()
    {
        Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged -= Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged;
    }

    void Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged(object sender, ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsNotConnected = e.NetworkAccess != NetworkAccess.Internet;
    }
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you use `IsNotConnected` for do you think it should notify on value change?

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in the event handler? How often does it get called?

Comment: Could you provide some more relevant code ?

Comment: @FreakyAli  Yes , it will notify the value change

Comment: @JianweiSun I used this blog for implementing this https://xamgirl.com/handling-connection-changes-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: it seems like this does not work in ios simulator. This may be a limitation of `Connectivity`, because the simulator used network is from Mac. You'd better test that in a physical device.

Answer (score 0):

The Forms lifecycle is somewhat different from the declarative lifecycle approach of native platform, and you can do this directly in the native ios lifecycle.

In `AppDelegate.cs`:

```
public override void OnActivated(UIApplication application)
    {
        Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged += Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged;
    }

 public override void DidEnterBackground(UIApplication uiApplication)
    {
        Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged -= Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged;
    }

 private void Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged(object sender, ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //...
    }
```

You can also check this [lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/application-lifecycle-demo#walkthrough).

on iOS 13 (and later), you need write them to `SceneDelegate` too.